# MASM 64 unresolved external symbol

Tags: windows, assembly, 64-bit

I am trying to run a very simple assembly langauge program from the command line, however I am getting lots of 'unresolved external symbol' errors e.g. for MessageBoxA and ExitProcess.  Are there obj files that have to be in the classpath?

I am not using C++.  I am tring to get a general idea of how assembly programming is done.

Comment: Why is this tagged as .net-assembly?

Comment: What is the command line you are executing?

Answer (score 0):

Try add at the beginning of your code EXTERN directives:

```
extrn  ExitProcess: PROC 
extrn  MessageBoxA: PROC 
; etc.
```